# UICollectionViewFlowLayout one row/section horizontal

Tags: ios

I have seen so many ways to get a carousel/one row/section in UICollectionView. But non is working probably, do you have a way.

I have the following:

```
@IBAction func openCollectionView(_ sender: Any) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: self.view.frame.height)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    collectionView!.delegate   = self
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.register(PDCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

    collectionView?.contentOffset.x = 20

    collectionView?.reloadData()
    collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()

    collectionView!.addBlurEffect()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

}
```

Comment: It is pretty easy, you would just need to set the collectionView's layout to horizontal, then in your dataSource method in your VC, return 1 for sections, and `yourDataArray.count` for itemsInSection

Comment: You actually don't even need to "return 1 for sections" as that is the default return value if the function isn't implemented.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618023-numberofsections

Answer (score 0):

Ok - simple enough:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width/2)+50, height: (self.view.frame.size.height/2)+50)
```

And for more complex cells:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```